# Generic way of handling concatenated table key

Tags: dynamic, abap, opensql

If I have a `tabkey` value, e.g., `DATA(lv_tabkey) = '1000041508773180000013000'.`, which is the concatenated value of all table keys for an entry and I know the name of the corresponding table:

How I can get the table entry for it without splitting `tabkey` **manually** and therefore having to write the order and length of each key field?

Full example:

```
" The first 3 chars always belong to the 'mandt' field 
" which can't be filtered in the SELECT, therefore 
" I ignore it and start with key2
DATA(lv_tabkey) = '1000041508773180000013000'.

"ToDo - how to make this generic? - START
DATA(lv_key2) = lv_tabkey+3(12).
DATA(lv_key3) = lv_tabkey+15(3).
DATA(lv_key4) = lv_tabkey+18(4).
DATA(lv_key5) = lv_tabkey+22(3).
DATA(lv_where) =      'key2 = ' && lv_key2 && 
                 ' AND key3 = ' && lv_key3 && 
                 ' AND key4 = ' && lv_key4 && 
                 ' AND key5 = ' && lv_key5.
"ToDo - how to make this generic? - END

SELECT *
  FROM table_x
  INTO TABLE DATA(lt_results)
  WHERE (lv_where).
```

I think I have to somehow iterate over the table fields, find out the keys and their length - but I don't know how to do this.

Comment: Unless it's a Z table, Can you post the actual table you are actually trying to access? I think what you need is to have a ``JOIN`` to the table where the tabkey is stored as a single field, so you can ``SELECT from table_x`` without splitting.

Comment: `how to make this generic?` no way. You always need to know the table (structure), field lengths, and the set of fields used for key. Only with these 3 parameters and RTTS you can construct generic method for parsing the key.

Comment: @Suncatcher then I don't know the correct wording for this - maybe dynamic? I just mean not having to do those '+18(4)'-things in the code manually.

Comment: @RaTiO but this question is about doing this for any table in general, that's why the actual table should not matter - so unless table_x also has a "tabkey" field, I don't see what a `JOIN` could do, if the tables have no common unique fields

Comment: Please edit your question: add one example because people don't understand what you mean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The statement you are seeking is:

> ASSIGN tabkey TO < structure> CASTING TYPE HANDLE r_type_struct.

Knowing type handle for the (table key) structure you can fill it with values in a generic way and query the table using the structure. Here is how:

```
DATA: handle      TYPE REF TO data,
      lref_struct TYPE REF TO cl_abap_structdescr.

FIELD-SYMBOLS: <key_fld> TYPE abap_componentdescr.

SELECT * UP TO 5000 ROWS
  FROM cdpos
  INTO TABLE @DATA(t_cdpos)
  WHERE tabname NOT LIKE '/%'.

LOOP AT t_cdpos ASSIGNING FIELD-SYMBOL(<fs_cdpos>).
  lref_struct ?= cl_abap_structdescr=>describe_by_name( <fs_cdpos>-tabname ).

* get key fields
  DATA(key_fields) = VALUE ddfields( FOR line IN lref_struct->get_ddic_field_list( ) WHERE ( keyflag NE space ) ( line ) ).

* filling key field components
  DATA(key_table) = VALUE abap_component_tab( FOR ls_key IN key_fields
                                              ( name = ls_key-fieldname
                                                type = CAST #( cl_abap_datadescr=>describe_by_name( ls_key-domname ) )
                                               )
                                            ).
* create key fields type handle
  TRY.
      DATA(r_type_struct) = cl_abap_structdescr=>create( key_table ).
    CATCH cx_sy_struct_creation .
  ENDTRY.

* create key type
  CHECK r_type_struct IS NOT INITIAL.
  CREATE DATA handle TYPE HANDLE r_type_struct.
  ASSIGN handle->* TO FIELD-SYMBOL(<structure>).

* assigning final key structure
  ASSIGN <fs_cdpos>-tabkey TO <structure> CASTING TYPE HANDLE r_type_struct.

* filling values
  LOOP AT key_table ASSIGNING <key_fld>.
    ASSIGN COMPONENT <key_fld>-name OF STRUCTURE <structure> TO FIELD-SYMBOL(<val>).
    CHECK sy-subrc = 0.
    <key_fld>-suffix = <val>.
  ENDLOOP.

  DATA(where_cond) = REDUCE string( INIT where = ` ` FOR <field> IN key_table WHERE ( name <> 'MANDT' ) NEXT where = where && <field>-name && ` = '` && <field>-suffix && `' AND ` ).
  where_cond = substring( val = where_cond off = 0 len = strlen( where_cond ) - 4 ).

  IF <fs_cdpos>-tabname = 'BNKA'.
    SELECT *
    INTO TABLE @DATA(lt_bnka)
    FROM bnka
    WHERE (where_cond).
  ENDIF.

ENDLOOP.
```

Here I built the sample on table `CDPOS` that contain table names and additionally concatenated key values in field `tabkey`, in other words exactly what you are trying to use.

In a loop it detects table types, builds the key and make SQL query in a generic way. Here I used table `BNKA` for simplicity, but SQL SELECT can be generized as well via field-symbol. Also I made a trick by filling values into the same tab that contains structure components, in `SUFFIX` field.

P.S. Before passing where condition into query make proper data type validation to avoid such errors as [SAPSQL_DATA_LOSS](https://blogs.sap.com/2019/08/08/open-sql-strict-mode-sapsql_data_loss-and-atc/), because with new syntax it makes a strict check.

Comment: Wow, I didn't expect it to be that difficult - but it is exactly what I was looking for and works perfectly - thanks!!!

Answer (score 1):

your use case reminds me that how I deal with Change Document key.(CDHDR/CDPOS). 
Hope it helps!

```
DATA:
  lv_tabkey  TYPE char50,
  ls_table   TYPE table_x.
FIELD-SYMBOLS:
  <ls_src_x> TYPE x,
  <ls_tgt_x> TYPE x.

"Add Client info the Table key if your table is Client dependent. 
CONCATENATE sy-mandt lv_tabkey INTO lv_tabkey.

ASSIGN lv_tab_key TO <ls_src_x> CASTING.
ASSIGN ls_table TO <ls_tgt_x> CASTING.
<ls_tgt_x> = <ls_src_x>.

"Now ls_table has the key info filled including MANDT if you have the MANDT in table key. 

SELECT *
  FROM table_x
    INTO TABLE DATA(lt_results)
    WHERE key2 = ls_table-key2 AND key3 = ls_table-key3
          AND key4 = ls_table-key4 AND key5 = ls_table_key5.
```